# How to position two block items on a single line

Tags: css

I'm trying aligned on one line sections new-setstion, user-section with inline-block but when I put text they diverge.

This is my css code, if you have better suggestions or criticisms please share them.

```
.page-content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.news-section {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 500px;
        min-width: 200px;
        background-color: #fff;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: left;
    }
    div.user-section {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 300px;
        min-width: 200px;
        background-color: #fff;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

[image: it is an image that illustrates the problem]

This is my html code

```
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="news-section">
    <div class="news-section-header">
        <h2>News</h2>
     </div>
        <!-- content -->
  </div>
<div class="user-section">
  <div class="user-section-header">
     <h2>User section</h2>
   </div>
<form  class="user-login-form" method="POST">
    <div><input type="email" name="user-name" placeholder="John-Doe@mail.com" /></div>
    <div><input type="password" name="user-pass" placeholder="*****" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="sub-button" value="Login"/></div>
    </form>
            <!-- another div content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Show the HTML. Assumably `.news-section, .user-section { vertical-align: top; }` will already solve the issue. And btw, it's "News", not "New's".

Comment: Тhank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oqvzraxs/, if I understood correctly your question.

I have added `display: inline-flex` to  `.page-content`

```
.page-content {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yes `{ vertical-align: top; }` also works.Thank you for the reply I would have, and your version of perches future.